# yocto linux systemd daemon

Tags: linux, daemon, yocto, systemd

I have an embedded device running a linux image built with Yocto. Also I have an application running on this system. 
I want to make daemon script for this application, so that it should start at boot, and could be started/ stopped like services in ubuntu (service app [start|stop|restart|status]).

What I have done until now:

```
[Unit]
Description=application

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/application start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/application stopType=simple
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

start() {
  exec blah-blah pwrOFF etc
}

stop() {
  exec blah-blah pwrON etc
}

case $1 in
  start|stop) "$1" ;;
esac
```

I don't know how to complete the functions start and stop, and also I don't know how to check the status. How this script should look like?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `systemctl enable/disable/status/start/stop deamon_name`